# Send data to the server using POST request with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

**What I want to do:**

- I'm trying to send data to my server using `$.post` jQuery shortcut.

**What is the problem:**

- My program doesn't enter in my `switch case`, maybe because my `action` it isn't sending properly.

**What I'm trying to do:**

- I created a table and one of my elements is a button with an `onclick` JavaScript function: `<button onclick='Delete()'></button>`.
- My JavaScript function:

```
function Delete(){
    $.post("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/res/?action=deleteRegistro", function(data){
        if(data){
            console.log("Deleteeeed");  
        }
        else {
            console.log("Not deleted :(");
       }
    });
}
```

- My `switch case` statement:

```
switch($_POST['action']){
    case 'deleteRegistro': // NOT OK
        ?>
            <script>
                alert("I'm in deleteRegistro");
            </script>
        <?php 
        
        break;
}
```

- What happen when I click on the button:

[image]

This, should work because I'm passing my action `deleteRegistro` in my post request to my server (php).

I need some help, what I'm doing wrong?

This is my full code if you want to check it out:

```
<?php

include_once(DIR_PLUGINS.'/alexcrudgenerator/main.php');

    $test = new GenerateCrud($_POST['tableName'], $_POST['id'], $_POST['tableFields']);

    switch($_POST['action']){
        
        case 'datosTabla': // OK.
            $res = json_decode($_POST['datos']);
            echo json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            
            break;
        
        case 'deleteRegistro': // NOT OK
            ?>
            <script>
                alert("I'm in deleteRegistro");
            </script>
            <?php 
            break;
            
        case 'showtable': // OK.
            
            $res = getEntireTable($_POST['tableName'], $_POST['id'], $_POST['tableFields']);
            $tableName = $_POST['tableName'];
            foreach ($res as $data){                
                $data->acción = "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button id='modificar_$data->id' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditar' value='edit'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button><button onclick='Delete()' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'><i class='material-icons' value='delete'>delete</i></button></div></div>"; 
                $resultados['data'][] = $data;
            }           
            
            $resultados = json_encode($resultados);
            
            foreach(json_decode($_POST['tableFields']) as $columnsDB){
                $fields[] = array('data'=>$columnsDB);
            }

            $fields[]['data'] = 'acción';
            $fields = json_encode($fields);
            
?>
            <head>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>
            
            <div class="container caja">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div>
                            <table id="tablaUsuarios" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed hover" style="width:100%" >
                                <thead class="text-center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <?php
                                            foreach (json_decode($_POST['tableFields']) as $columnsTH){
                                                 echo '<th>' . strtoupper($columnsTH) . '</th>';
                                            }
                                            echo '<th>ACCIÓN</th>';
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>

                function Delete(){
                    $.post("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/res/?action=deleteRegistro", function(data){
                        if(data){
                            console.log("Deleteeeed");  
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("Not deleted :(");
                        }
                    });
                }
                
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var datos= <?=$resultados?>;
                    var dynamicColumns = <?=$fields?>;
                    datos = JSON.stringify(datos);
                    
                    $('#tablaUsuarios').DataTable({
                        "language": {"url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/i18n/Spanish.json"},
                        "paging": true,
                        "lengthChange": true,
                        "searching": true,
                        "info": true,
                        "autoWidth": true,
                        "scrollX": true,

                        "ajax":{
                            "url": '<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/',
                            "method": 'POST',
                            "data":{action: "datosTabla", datos: datos}
                        },

                        "columns": dynamicColumns
                    });
                })
            </script>
<?php
        break;      
}
?>
```

Comment: You've not described what the exact problem is, or your goal. However I can tell you that returning a mix of HTML/JS from the PHP in the manner you are will not be executed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added my problem. Sorry!

Comment: You should send your `action` as part of the request body instead of sending it as part of the URL. jQuery's `post` method https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ accepts a `data` property, which you can to pass your action to the server as part of the request body. Something like `data: { action: 'deleteRegistro' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting to the file in a wrong way that might be the issue as far as I could understand it.

```
$.post("URL", {
            action: "deleteRegistro"
        }, function (data, status) {
        //  alert (data + '\n' + "status" + status);
            if (status === 'error') {
                console.log("Not deleted"); // For debugging purpose
            } else if (status === 'success') {
              console.log("Deleted successfully");
            }
        });
```

Put the correct URl in place of "URL"
No need to change anything in switch case tho.

But even after this you may not see your data in table got deleted, you need to refresh the page.

As you have all these functionalities in single page I suggest you to use hidden form to post the data.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, but still without enter in my `switch case` ... Curious ...

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the action in the query string, not the request body, so it will be available in `$_GET` and not `$_POST`.

The PHP superglobals `$_GET` and `$_POST` do not refer (directly) to the request type. They refer to where an HTML form will put data from an input depending on the `method` attribute.

Any kind of HTTP request can include a query string in the URL and this will be put in the `$_GET` superglobal.

Not all HTTP requests can have a request body, but many (including POST and PUT) can. PHP will populate `$_POST` with data in the request body if it is encoded in a format PHP understands and the `Content-Type` is correct. (PHP might also check the request type and only do this for POST requests, it isn't something I've investigated).

Comment: Okay, thank you for the explanation, I get it. Now, I don't know how to pass my action in my URL to enter in my case ... I have to use POST method